# equal spacing between text of different size in CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I get equal spacing between lines of different sizes with CSS?  Here is my base html:

```
  <div style="font-size: 200%">A</div>
  <div style="font-size: 100%">B C</div>
  <div style="font-size: 50%">D E F</div>
  <div style="font-size: 25%">G H I</div>
```

I want the same spacing between each line despite different font sizes (i.e. the red arrows below should be equal).  I can't figure out how to do this with the CSS line-height property.

[image]

Comment: I guess it could be done without margin and rem if needed, lookout for  my answer. let me know if it works.. thanks.. gud question by the way

Comment: I guess the chosen answer will not work for multiple lines in the same div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the other answers are almost there, but line-height is a little different. The way I think about it is that line-height is the amount of space from the **center** of the letter. So if your line-height is 50px, there will be 25px space above the middle of the letter and 25px space below the middle of the letter. This makes the line 50px tall.

So to make the space between them even, I would use a margin-bottom and set the line-height to something that looks like it butts right up to the top and bottom of the letter (probably different depending on the font you use). In my example below, I set the line-height to .7 (you can see how it butts up to the letter's actual baseline and top height with the red border. Then I gave a margin value with rem units so that it is relative to the original page font size, not the div itself with a unique font size.

```css
body {
  font-size: 24px;
}

div {
    line-height: .7;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div style="font-size: 200%">A</div>
<div style="font-size: 100%">B C</div>
<div style="font-size: 50%">D E F</div>
<div style="font-size: 25%">G H I</div>
```

Comment: Will it work for multi-line texts. meaning if I had to type B C D .... Z and the second div gets two lines.. I fear the margin of 1rem is relative to the div and not the line.

Comment: Well if you want exact spacing between divs and lines, regardless of text size, you'll need to do some calculation based on the understanding of how line height relates to the text, and there will be slight variation between fonts and how much vertical space they consume.

Answer (score 4):

Use a fixed line height:

```
div {
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Example:

```css
body {
  font-size: 24px;
}

div {
    line-height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div style="font-size: 200%">A</div>
<div style="font-size: 100%">B C</div>
<div style="font-size: 50%">D E F</div>
<div style="font-size: 25%">G H I</div>
```

Comment: Might want display:table-cell; vertical-align: center; very nice, nm

Comment: didn't look like the spacing was correct, but i see that it is :)

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the space between the divs is uniform, but the actual space between the letter forms is not. (Bigger space between the bottom of DEF and the top of GHI than there is between the bottom of A and the top of BC)

Comment: This doesn't work -- a larger font size will take up more of the "allotted" 50px causing the whitespace to increase with smaller font sizes.

Comment: Is that not what you asked for? Maybe I misunderstood your question

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the browsers you need to support, you can use the `rem` unit, which is really powerful.

It uses the base font size of the document and uses multiplies it. xample:

```
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.large-font {
  font-size: 500%;
  margin-bottom: 10rem; /* this will be 160 pixels! */
}

.tiny-font {
  font-size: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 10rem; /* this will still be 160 pixels! */
}
```

This is really flexible, because if you change the base font-size: the margins will scale with it (whereas pixel values are fixed).

Answer (score 0):

Include the line-height defenition in the  section of yout HTML document addressing the body of the document if that's what you're after or in a separate ".css" file and include the source in the  section "".

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body 
{
  line-height: 1.5;
}
</style>
</head>
```

**Mohammed Ashiq** (Post Above) voted down my answer for some unicorn reason. The code I wrote works as intended. Would not have put it up if it didn't

Answer (score 0):

--EDIT--

The below code will not work. This is exactly what moobs did. I realise that I have misunderstood. I have posted the correct answer again. Try it out in the snippet it works!

--

The trick is to use the line height as fixed for all the font sizes PROVIDED YOU HAVE TO GIVE THE LINE HEIGHT MORE THAN THE BIGGEST FONT.

```css
p.small {
    line-height: 40px;
}

p.big {
    line-height: 40px;
     font-size: 30px;
}

p.too-big {
    line-height: 40px;
     font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<p class="small">
This is a paragraph with a smaller font
</p>

<p class="big">
This is a paragraph with a big font.
</p>

<p class="too-big">
This is a paragraph with a bigger font
</p>
```

If you give the line height less than the biggest font size, you are actually forcing the browser to display a bigger sized text into a smaller line. that is the reason why you get different line height for different sizes

Answer (score 0):

The right answer for this would be mere calculation. All we need is to get equal amount of whitespaces. The whitespace between two lines are contributed half from the line above and half from the next line. So if we make sure each line contributes 10px for example top and below apart from its font size, we could achieve this. The code snippet will help you get the right answer because, the answer chosen will not work for multiple line elements.

```css
p{
vertical-align: top;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
p.small {
    line-height: 40px;
font-size: 20px;
}

p.big {
    line-height: 50px;
     font-size: 30px;
}

p.too-big {
    line-height: 60px;
     font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<p class="small">
This is a paragraph with a smaller font
</p>

<p class="big">
This is a paragraph with a big font.
</p>

<p class="too-big">
This is a paragraph with a bigger font
</p>
```